# Graphical representation of unconditional expected value

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditioning

First, let tell you that I've being struggling with the concept of **unconditional expectation for linear regression**. For conditional expectation is easier:

We know that the conditional expectation function is defined by the average of all the possible values that $Y$ can take given a certain value of $X$. And then , if we take every of those averaged $Y$ values, corresponding to all the $X$'s values we have, and link them with a line, we are going to have the **conditional expectation function**. For that same data, if we fit a linear regression, the function of that regression is supposed to be the same, or at least the best approximation to the **conditional expectation function**. Something like this (source: https://www.timlrx.com/2018/02/26/notes-on-regression-approximation-of-the-conditional-expectation-function/):

[image: CEF]

---

For unconditional expectation we know that our value does not depend on the value that $X$ takes:

$$E(Y)= a + bX$$

And with that, we say that $Y$ take a constant value for every number that $x$'s can take: it takes and average.

As far as I know, we use the unconditional expectation form for a linear regression when our $X$ variable is fixed, it is no random. That is, we use unconditional expectation when we are performing an experiment, where we consciously make $X$ take a certain value.

I still cannot understand, how we are supposed to imagine in unconditional expectation, our $Y$ value taking a constant value for group of $X$'s. And the thing is:

if in a **conditional expectation mode of regression**, we are expecting that our linear regression approximates to the **conditional expectation function**, in a **unconditional expectation regression**, how we are supposed to see that our linear regression line approximates a **constant value of $Y$**. Wouldn't that be a constant line with zero slope?

I still don't know if I'm misinterpreting all this, but it has been confusing me around for a good time.

Comment: Your **unconditional expectation regression** what is it? I have never met such an animal!

Comment: Hello, I'm a asumming that we can make two kinds of regressions, one where our  x is fixed, and our Y can be modelled unconditionally, and another where our X is random, and we use a conditional expected value for Y. I would be very helpful if you can make this concept of conditional and unconditional for me :)